# Tool for finding all uses of move assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm introducing move semantics in a C++ library.
There is some legacy client 
code that uses the library that breaks because some assumptions were made
about the assignment operator that are invalid when assignment
is really move assignment.  This is a combination of a lack of clear
documentation in the library and some questionable practices in the
client code.  Nevertheless, I'd like to find a way to easily find all 
places in the code where the move assignment operator for a template
class is used.

I've figured out a way to do this by forcing a compiler error when 
the move assignment is invoked.  With gcc, if this is a direct invocation, 
I get the line number in the source code of the invocation. Unfortunately,
if it is an indirect invocation, I don't get the line number.
I also tried clang, but no luck there either.

The issue is this.
In the template class of interest, say template<class T> Foo { ... },
I can define the move assignment operator so that compilation
fails when it is instantiated with any type T.
This gives me the line number I want if client code
invokes it directly.
However, if there is a class X that has a member, say Foo<int>,
and X gets an implicitly defined move assignment operator,
then an invocation of this operator gets flagged as an error,
but the only line number I get in gcc and clang is the
line number of the definition of class X,
which is not very helpful.

Does anybody know of any tools to help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic

Comment: You better reword your question to ask for a *way* to achieve what you want rather than a *tool*, otherwise it'll be closed in no time.

Comment: Well, regardless of how my question was phrased, I ended up getting a great answer...so there's that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark your move constructor as `[[deprecated]]`.

For following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct A
{
    A() {}
    [[deprecated]] A(A &&) {/*...*/}
};

struct B
{
    A<int> a;
};

int main()
{
    B x;
    B y((B&&)x);
}
```

GCC gives me this warning:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'B::B(B&&)':
main.cpp:9:12: warning: 'A<T>::A(A<T>&&) [with T = int]' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     struct B
            ^
main.cpp:6:24: note: declared here
         [[deprecated]] A(A &&) {/*...*/}
                        ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:19: note: synthesized method 'B::B(B&&)' first required here 
         B y((B&&)x);
                   ^
```

Which contains all the line numbers you want.

---

As OP noticed, one can also use `__attribute__((deprecated))` to support older GCC versions.

Comment: Perfect!  One needs gcc 5 for this to work, or clang 5. But thanks a lot!!

Comment: Actually, __attribute__((deprecated) also works in gcc 4.8, which is also nice

Comment: @Victor You're welcome! You probably should consider pressing the green tick on the left of the answer [to indicate that your problem was solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Okey dokey...green tick pressed...sorry about that! Still learning how things work here